# Facing issues while importing third party (pygoogle) library in main.py for making android apk via buildozer

Tags: android, python, linux, kivy

I am trying to importing pygoogle by `import pygoogle` in my main.py but when i make an app via buildozer , in logcat i am finding that `no module named pygoogle`  I have installed pygoogle in my kali linux os and then i went to usr/local/lib/python2.7 and copied pygoogle folder to my home folder where my main.py is.....then i tried again but still same error and then i went `distribute.sh -m 'kivy pygoogle` everything went good but still was facing same error and then i went to buildozer and in requirments added pygoogle but in aviable module pygoogle is not showing by buildozer .... not with pygoogle only ..with all lbrary i am facing same problem ... any solution some know ???I am not linux expert

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a pure python module, and it's on pypi, you can just add it to requirements in buildozer, it doesn't need a specific recipe.